# Continuous wavelet transform with complex Morlet function

Tags: wavelet-analysis

The complex [Morlet function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlet_wavelet) is defined as:

$$Ψ(t,f_c,f_b)= \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ \pi f_{b} } }\exp(-t^2/f_b)\exp(\jmath 2πf_ct)$$

where $f_b$ and $f_c$ are two important parameters in modifying the complex Morlet wavelet.  It seems that *Mathematica* doesn't support complex Morlet transform and Its only support real morlet function that I am not interested to use. I'm into complex wavelet function. *Mathematica* only has Gabor transform for complex wavelets, and Gabor transform only has one parameter to be tuned.
so I need complex morlet function to run continues wavelet transform.
Also I want to define $f_b$ and $f_c$ of the complex morlet function myself.
 Can I make a complex Morlet wavalet transform by changing Gabor's parameter?  How can I change $f_b$ and $f_c$ in it?
can I define a new wavelet exactly like the equation of complex morlet?

P.S: Actually I am a *MATLAB* user and as such I don't really know anything about the flexibility of *Mathematica*, but the reason why I came here is that *Mathematica* has the [`InverseContinuousWaveletTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseContinuousWaveletTransform.html).

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more readable... please check the equation you've entered and make sure it is correct. Secondly, please quantify what you mean by "It seems that Mathematica doesn't support complex Morlet transform." Please include your code so that we can understand what you tried to do.

Comment: @rm-rf thanks for editing .

Comment: is your question not answered by the relevant documentation of [`MeyerWavelet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeyerWavelet.html)? Have you seen the section on basic uses and wavelet transforms?

Comment: @gpap I am looking for complex Morlet , not other wavelet basis. look at my edit plz

Comment: Look here for a tutorial about defining your own wavelet. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningYourOwnWavelet.html

Comment: @bill-s Indeed, the tutorial is a good reference, but I don't think you can generate the filter coefficients for continuous wavelets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT:**

First, a note: As the usage of options, parameters and functions listed below is not documented, be advised that they still need proper tuning and/or may not work at all.

```
CMorletWavelet[]["WaveletQ"] := True
CMorletWavelet[]["OrthogonalQ"] := False
CMorletWavelet[]["BiorthogonalQ"] := False
CMorletWavelet[]["WaveletFunction"] := 1/Sqrt[π] Exp[2 I π 2 #1] Exp[-#1^2] &
CMorletWavelet[]["FourierFactor"] := 4 π/(6 + Sqrt[2 + 6^2])
CMorletWavelet[]["FourierTransform"] := Function[{Wavelets`NonOrthogonalWaveletsDump`wt, 
   Wavelets`NonOrthogonalWaveletsDump`s},
  π^(-1/4)HeavisideTheta[Wavelets`NonOrthogonalWaveletsDump`wt + $MachineEpsilon] 
  Exp[-(1/2) (Wavelets`NonOrthogonalWaveletsDump`wt Wavelets`NonOrthogonalWaveletsDump`s
  - π Sqrt[2/Log[2]])^2]]
```

Now you can use the built-in wavelet-related functions:

```
Plot[{Re@WaveletPsi[CMorletWavelet[], x], Im@WaveletPsi[CMorletWavelet[], x]},
     {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}]
```

> [image: wavelet_plot]

```
snd = Play[Sum[Sin[2000 2^t n t], {n,5 }], {t, 2, 3}]

csd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[snd, CMorletWavelet[]]

WaveletScalogram[csd]
```

> [image: Sound scalogram]

```
InverseContinuousWaveletTransform[csd, CMorletWavelet[]]
```

> [image: Play sound]

This sound compression works just fine !

```
(* A simple example *)
cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[Range[10], CMorletWavelet[]]
WaveletScalogram[cwd]
```

> [image: Scalogram]

```
 InverseContinuousWaveletTransform[cwd, CMorletWavelet[]]
```

> ```
> {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.}
> ```

This works just as expected, but using numbers larger than `63` results in ..

```
 cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[Range[64], CMorletWavelet[]]
 WaveletScalogram[cwd]
```

> [image: Scalogram]

```
 InverseContinuousWaveletTransform[cwd, CMorletWavelet[]]
```

> ```
> {0.500005, 4.38214, 6.69958, 10.625, 12.6907, 16.5033, 18.2989, 
> 21.8762, 23.3564, 26.6196, 27.7395, 30.6377, 31.3658, 33.8706, 
> 34.1929, 36.2965, 36.2168, 37.9296, 37.4675, 38.8152, 38.0038, 
> 39.0243, 37.9069, 38.647, 37.274, 37.7859, 36.2116, 36.551, 34.8323, 
> 35.0564, 33.2508, 33.4173, 31.5827, 31.7492, 29.9436, 30.1677, 
> 28.449, 28.7884, 27.2141, 27.726, 26.353, 27.0931, 25.9757, 26.9962, 
> 26.1848, 27.5325, 27.0704, 28.7832, 28.7035, 30.8071, 31.1294, 
> 33.6342, 34.3623, 37.2605, 38.3804, 41.6436, 43.1238, 46.7011, 
> 48.4967, 52.3093, 54.375, 58.3004, 60.6179, 64.5}
> ```

One of the reasons for this lies in the fact that I used the Fourier Transform of the original [`MorletWavelet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorletWavelet.html) which is a built-in predicate and quite different in implementation from the one I used. There are probably other parameters I need to set up properly, but I can't seem to find them, because, like I said, the usage is undocumented.

---

I know you came here because of the [`InverseContinuousWaveletTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseContinuousWaveletTransform.html), but at that time of the day, or should I say night, I can't really think any more and will continue when I have more time to do so, unfortunately...

Note: As you are a *MATLAB* user I implemented the *Complex Morlet wavelet* according to *THEIR* documentation.

**Preliminaries**

For simplicity we assume that smallest wavelet scale is equal to `1` and we use a rather short data set.

I also used the following pages from the documentation (A-Z)

- [`ContinuousWaveletData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContinuousWaveletData.html)
- [`ContinuousWaveletTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContinuousWaveletTransform.html)
- [`WaveletScale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WaveletScale.html)
- [`WaveletScalogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WaveletScalogram.html)

**Implementation**

```
(* Example data set *)

data = {1, 2, 3, 4};

(* Parameters *)

noct = Floor@Log[2, (data // Length)/2]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
nvoc = 4;

(* Scaling parameter *)

s[oct_, voc_] := N[2^(oct - 1) 2^(voc/nvoc)]

(* Defining the wavelet function *)

ComplexMorlet[n_, band_, centerFreq_] := 
    1/Sqrt[π band] Exp[2 I π centerFreq n] Exp[-n^2/band]

(* Example expansion *)

ComplexMorlet[x, 1, 2]
```

> ```
> E^(4 I π x - x^2)/Sqrt[π]
> ```

```
Plot[{Re@ComplexMorlet[x, 1, 2], Im@ComplexMorlet[x, 1, 2]}, {x, -3, 3},
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}, PlotRange -> All, 
     Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

> [image: Plot]

```
(* Wavelet transform of a sampled sequence *)

 w[u_, oct_, voc_] := 1/s[oct, voc] Sum[data[[k]]
     Conjugate[ComplexMorlet[(k - u)/s[oct, voc], 1, 2]], {k, 1, data // Length}]

(* Performing the wavelet transform on our example data set *)

Table[w[k, 1, voc], {k, data // Length}, {voc, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{0.228074 + 0.361025 I, 0.0610598 - 0.123408 I, 
>      0.283659 - 0.583475 I, 1.15175 + 3.47516*10^-16 I},
>    {0.486587 + 0.340747 I, 0.0693978 - 0.058132 I, 0.786587 - 0.662852 I, 
>      1.85808 + 3.10964*10^-16 I}, 
>    {0.821662 + 0.446737 I, -0.0236108 - 0.295969 I, 1.47435 - 0.380752 I, 
>      2.26824 + 5.67838*10^-17 I}, 
>    {1.57014 - 0.595682 I, 1.02407 + 0.281895 I, 1.47482 + 0.762858 I, 
>      2.02475 - 2.84949*10^-16 I}}
> ```

```
(* Wavelet Scalogram using ComplexMorlet[x, 1, 2] *)

WaveletScalogram@ContinuousWaveletData[
 {{1, 1} -> {0.22807383843702972` + 0.36102529036876024` I, 
       0.06105984372279422` - 0.12340783119864777` I, 
       0.28365883675526904` - 0.5834746966816698` I, 
       1.1517469935306757` + 3.4751640646106677`*^-16 I},
  {1, 2} -> {0.4865866432814967` + 0.3407467247569226` I, 
       0.06939782717412021` - 0.05813200432524761` I, 
       0.7865874222126943` - 0.6628516103818837` I, 
       1.8580796599037956` + 3.1096385445125467`*^-16 I},
  {1, 3} -> {0.8216617511105463` + 
       0.44673675942817265` I, -0.02361080340458542` - 
       0.2959689122870983` I, 
       1.4743517412825382` - 0.3807516306374966` I, 
       2.26823511807995` + 5.678382044215492`*^-17 I},
  {1, 4} -> {1.570143054029254` - 0.5956822545417808` I, 
       1.024067417876664` + 0.2818946441776095` I, 
       1.4748223337693926` + 0.7628582023394818` I, 
       2.024752422313301` - 2.849488941725102`*^-16 I}}]
```

> [image: WaveletScalogram]

```
(* Wavelet Scalogram using ComplexMorlet[x, 1, 10] *)

WaveletScalogram@ContinuousWaveletData@
 {{1, 1} -> {0.11634486079523618` - 0.17990847470866217` I, 
       0.9410569485064904` - 0.3524175549056541` I, 
       0.9995892268140318` + 0.3575695443712028` I, 
       1.1517469935306757` + 2.5826325630023094`*^-15 I},
 {1, 2} -> {0.2085276338912312` - 0.15114828701865127` I, 
      1.8062819251440743` - 0.3772206439472593` I, 
      1.813592761954768` + 0.36136020250254647` I, 
      1.8580796599037956` + 1.5548192722562736`*^-15 I},
 {1, 3} -> {0.2547509048762912` - 0.27877696228455096` I, 
      2.5401537117071564` - 0.16692666476822` I, 
      2.402824979378204` + 0.10553538050034861` I, 
      2.26823511807995` + 2.8391910221077465`*^-16 I},
 {1, 4} -> {1.3309683457126755` + 0.3296339838999044` I, 
      2.319228847343012` + 0.4019097092762081` I, 
      2.1426745757435186` - 0.3492240227193354` I, 
      2.024752422313301` - 1.6360071035367952`*^-15 I}}
```

> [image: WaveletScalogram 2]

Comment: I will improve this, if I have time tomorrow, so we can benefit from the `"WaveletQ"` and `"OrthogonalQ"` properties and make the whole process more refined for the end user.

Comment: Thanks loads for your neat and specified answer. would you help me for _inverse_ continues_wavelet transform please?    
why the scalogram plot looks like that? I used to work with more clear and continues plots. I guess its for division between scale, I used to use this relationship for scales:  $$ s_{j}=  s_{0} 2^{j  \delta _{j} } , j=0,1,2,... J$$
$$J= \delta  j^{-1} log_{2} ( \frac{N \delta t}{ s_{0} } )$$
and i was using $\delta _{j}$ = 0.01   Thanks for answering

Comment: Yes, I will, I am sorry for the delay, but was on a short trip. I have already written everything, so expect it in a few hours. The scalogram looks like this because of the data set I used.

Comment: @Electricman You can check out the edit :)

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. I have 2 other question. 1)can I implement DWT by this built complex morlet function, and how?   2) where did you define scale range? was it set by this code Range[10]; and can I dvide between scales ranges to get better and continuous scalogram? ? Thanks in advance Nikola

Comment: Nope, it is not suitable to implement DWT using continuous wavelet. You can try with a range of discrete wavelet families and use the tutorial @bill-s posted. Nowhere, *Mathematica* internally computes the needed scales, as you can read in the documentation centre. `Range[10]` is actually `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}` - the data set I used as an example. For such a small sample, I think, you will always get such a 'discretized' scalogram.

Comment: Nice answer. Since the symbols are local to `Function`, you can use a simple variable name instead of attaching it to the ``Wavelets`NonOrthogonalWaveletsDump` `` context...

Comment: @rm-rf Thank you! I did it this way, because I think that's the actual implementation of the other wavelet families in *Mathematica*, but can't really tell :)

Comment: @NikolaDimitrov, thanks, yes I know that its not well to run DWT with continues wavelets. but I meant can I run DWT with a complex morlet wavelet too? not with its exact function, for example in matlab we have Daubechies and meyer for CWT and DWT, but the Continues function of Daubechies  looks different from its discrete version. the discrete version is actually discrete function with a low and high pass filter. actually I need to compare CWT with DWT for complex morlet function. we call this DWT implement ion Mallat filter.

Comment: @NikolaDimitrov It appears that way because it is defined in a package. For example, if you have a package ``BeginPackage["Foo`"]`` and then a context ``Begin["`Private`"]``, then if you define `Function[{x}, ...]` inside, it will appear (in a standard notebook) as ``Function[{Foo`Private`x}, ...]``

Comment: Uff, even for one second I did not think about packages .. Thanks, @rm-rf :)  Electricman: Later today, when I get back home I will research and try to implement the features you are interested in.

Comment: @NikolaDimitrov, Thank you very much Nikola