# Extracting information from the result of ContinuousWaveletTransform

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

I'm trying to analysis a signal and identify some time-frequency information of it. For example, around which time the specific frequency arrives. It appears that Mathematica has very powerful wavelet analysis functions builtin suitable for my job. I've being reading the documentation of them, but still can't get it. In particular I don't really understand what the functions `ContinuousWaveletTransform` and `WaveletScalogram` do.

For example, for this example in the document,

```
data = Table[
   Piecewise[{{Sin[2 π 10 t], 0 <= t < 1/4}, {Sin[2 π 25 t], 
      1/4 <= t < 1/2}, {Sin[2 π 50 t], 
      1/2 <= t < 3/4}, {Sin[2 π 100 t], 3/4 <= t <= 1}}], {t, 0, 
    1, 1/1023}];
ListLinePlot[data, AspectRatio -> 0.2]
```

[image]

```
cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, 
   DGaussianWavelet[5], {Automatic, 12}];
WaveletScalogram[cwd, ColorFunction -> "RustTones"]
```

[image]

The above example shows the maps of a 1D time signal into a 2D time-frequency representation.

So my questions are:

1. In the documentation, it says `WaveletScalogram` "plots wavelet vector coefficients", what that really mean? What is the x and y axis represent? In my understanding the time-frequency 2d plot is kind of like a musical score where the time axis is horizontal and the frequencies (notes) are plotted on a vertical axis. It this understanding correct?
2. Is there a way to see the identify frequencies in the signal from the 2D plot? For example, we can see four difference frequencies from the 2d plot, can we read off their frequencies from the corresponding y value?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you are right. [`WaveletScalogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WaveletScalogram.html) produces a plot that is very similar in behaviour to that used in music. Here, the octave axis is also logarithmic: `-Log[2,b]`, meaning that the frequency at the next octave is doubled.
We can illustrate this by a simple example - Consider a signal with a `freq = 440Hz` and a signal with double that `freq = 880Hz`. Now, knowing that higher frequencies are resolved at lower octaves and lower frequencies at higher octaves we can do the following calculation:

```
N[Log[440]/Log[2]]
```

> ```
>  8.78136
> ```

```
N[Log[880]/Log[2]]
```

> ```
>  9.78136
> ```

What this shows us is that two signals with frequencies respectively `ω` and `2ω` are resolved at octaves next to each other.

And yes, you can identify a certain frequency from the [`WaveletScalogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WaveletScalogram.html). You have the following relation between the scales used in the wavelet transform,[`ContinuousWaveletTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContinuousWaveletTransform.html) or [`DiscreteWaveletTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscreteWaveletTransform.html), and the specific frequency:
$$F_{a}=\frac{F_{c}}{a \Delta }$$

- `a` is a scale
- `Δ` is the [`SampleRate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SampleRate.html)
- Fc is the center frequency of a wavelet in Hz
- Fa is the frequency corresponding to the scale `a`, in Hz

For ease of use we will give `Fc = 1`. For a better localisation search the Internet for the exact centre frequency corresponding to the wavelet family you are using.
Now, all we need is the [`SampleRate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SampleRate.html) which by default is equal to `8000Hz` and the scales used in the wavelet transform you gave as an example.

```
freq = (#1[[1]] -> 8000/#1[[2]] &) /@ cwd["Scales"]
```

> ```
>   {{1, 1} -> 20230.3, {1, 2} -> 19094.9, {1, 3} -> 18023.2, {1, 4} -> 17011.6,
>      {1, 5} -> 16056.8, {1, 6} -> 15155.6, {1, 7} -> 14305., {1, 8} -> 13502.1,
>      {1, 9} -> 12744.3, {1, 10} -> 12029., {1, 11} -> 11353.9, {1, 12} -> 10716.6,
>      {2, 1} -> 10115.2, {2, 2} -> 9547.44, {2, 3} -> 9011.58, {2, 4} -> 8505.8,
>      {2, 5} -> 8028.41, {2, 6} -> 7577.81, {2, 7} -> 7152.5, {2, 8} -> 6751.06,
>      {2, 9} -> 6372.15, {2, 10} -> 6014.51, {2, 11} -> 5676.94, {2, 12} -> 5358.32, ... }
> ```

We need to filter the frequency we are interested in and we will be able to say where we can find it in the scalogram. Say we are interested in the `ω = 50Hz`

```
Cases[freq, u_ /; 49 <= Last[u] <= 51]
```

> ```
> {{9, 9} -> 49.7824}
> ```

Look back at the scalogram and locate octave `9` and voice `9` - and there it is !

At first I thought that the logical step to perform was to scale the data before passing it to the [`WaveletScalogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WaveletScalogram.html). And since we are using `-Log` scale you need to scale by a factor `2`. I am still trying to figure out how to do this in [`WaveletScalogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WaveletScalogram.html). If that isn't something you need really fast you can use the following approach:

```
ListPlot[Abs@Reverse[Last /@ cwd[All]], PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: Linear scale scalogram]

Or optionally in 3D:

```
ListPlot3D[Abs@Reverse[Last /@ cwd[All]], PlotRange -> All, 
        Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", 
        AxesLabel -> {"time", "octaves", "magnitude"}]
```

> [image: Wavelet Scalogram in 3D]

---

Edit by xslittlegrass

Sometimes we need to plot the wavelet transform scalogram in unit of frequencies rather than scales. The following shows how to do that (Thanks @Rojo and @MichaelE2 for discussion).

```
sampleRate=1023;
data = Table[
  Piecewise[{{Sin[2 π 10 t], 0 <= t < 1/4}, {Sin[2 π 25 t], 
     1/4 <= t < 1/2}, {Sin[2 π 50 t], 
     1/2 <= t < 3/4}, {Sin[2 π 100 t], 3/4 <= t <= 1}}], {t, 0, 1,
    1/sampleRate}];
cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, 
  DGaussianWavelet[5], {Automatic, 12}, SampleRate -> sampleRate]
```

Note that the frequencies in wavelet plot is characterized by pairs of numbers {octave, voice}. A octave means the frequency is doubled, and voices are further divisions of a octave. For example, if f1==2*f2, then f1 is one octave above f2.
These wavelet scales can be converted into frequencies easily in a very clean way thanks to the "Scales" and "FourierFactor" properties of the wavelet transform data.

This calculates the frequency (in Hz) of each octave (corresponding to {1,1}, {2,1}, ... in the {octave,voice} notation.)

```
freq = (cwd["SampleRate"]/(#*cwd["Wavelet"]["FourierFactor"])) & /@
       (Thread[{Range[cwd["Octaves"]], 1}] /. cwd["Scales"]);
```

this gives expression for ticks at each octave

```
ticks = Transpose[{Range[Length[freq]], freq}];
```

this display the wavelet scalogram in the frequency.

```
WaveletScalogram[cwd, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{ticks, Automatic}, Automatic}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Frequency(Hz)"}, 
 ColorFunction -> "RustTones"]
```

[image]

From above plots, one can see that there are frequencies at around 10Hz, 25Hz, 50Hz and 100Hz as we have in the signal.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. What does the voice 9 mean, and where should I look at? And do you know is there a way to produce the linear scale instead of the log scale on vertical axis?

Comment: Also when right click on the WaveletScalogram and choose coordinates of it, what does the second coordinate stand for?

Comment: You should not look for it in the `WaveletScalogram` - look up the octave and try to localise the signal in time. Voice is just the the second coordinate from the pair `(octave, voice)`. Wavelet transform constructs those pairs and then assigns them a scale and each scale represents a vector containing wavelet coefficients. See "wavelet vector coefficients" in your post - that's them :) Well, bear in mind that we are using a `-Log` scale and the numbers you see are not reversed and the logarithm of them not taken.

Comment: A reason for the down vote  ?

Comment: What do you mean? It shows me no downvotes on this answer. See the screen crop [here](http://imgur.com/j7zHzK1)

Comment: I am sorry it is an unupvote.. And It is not from you, as I can tell :)

Comment: @Sektor If I use a MorletWavelet[] (which I think looks similar to DGaussianWavelet[4], which gives a similar result to DGaussianWavelet[5]) I get continuous horizontal bands, which is what I would expect if the Y axis was frequency and the pixel values amplitude. Does DGaussianWavelet[5] encode amplitude information differently? (i.e., why do the values drop between the peaks?)

Comment: @DrBubbles Can you show me an example ? If I understand correctly you are asking me why there are blobs instead of a continuous band in a wavelet scalogram, right ?

Comment: @Sektor yes that was the question. I read more and found a good description by 'endolith': http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/7911/reading-the-wavelet-transform-plot   I then found your implementation of a Complex Morlet wavelet for mathematica and realized that is probably what I should be using: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33549/continuous-wavelet-transform-with-complex-morlet-function   Now I need to figure out how to extract the instantaneous power spectrum at each point as the numbers from Scalogram appear to be normalized to 1. Maybe I should ask as a new question?

Comment: I realize now the wavelet coefficients in the scalogram aren't normalized it was just a coincidence of my test data.

Comment: (the maximum of the coefficients was a little over one). How do the wavelet coefficients relate to the amplitude of the frequency components at each point in the original data?

Comment: To whomever downvoted the answer -- care to explain the reason behind it, so that I can improve my answers in the future ?

Comment: But... how you change Time-axis?

Comment: @Sssur By specifying the `SampleRate`