# Signal processing by means of WaveletTransform

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

I updated my question to explain what I want. 
**I have the voltage-time curve from the real industial object.** This curve was gotten from the digital oscilloscope:

[image: Oscillogram]

As you can see it has **hight-frequency (kHz) interference**.
We extracted data from the oscilloscope into the Microsoft Excel file and here it is:
http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g3c9169c7c6eb991d999470396248137bf77d4cabe

Using this data we reconstructed the curve (in MathCAD). As an equivalent to time-axis we have n-axis ("n" - number of the point; every point corresponds to certain moment of time; in all we have 4000 points for 8 ms):

[image: curve]

Using Fourier Transofrm we got frequency spectrum **(amp-freq curve)**:

[image: fourier frequency spectrum]

Inasmuch as this signal is **nonstationary**, the usage of *Fourier Transform* **is not appropriate**. So we used *Fast Wavelet Transform* and the result was quite different (and **probably** correct). This is an **amp-point curve** which is similar to the recostructed source curve, but there are displayed amplitudes for 4,7 - 5,5 kHz frequencies (for different wavelet coefficients), which appeared exactly in these moments:

[image: wavelet frequency spectrum]

And now by some reason there is a need to process the source data in Wolfram Mathematica, also because it is far and away more powerful than MathCAD. But Mathematica is something new for me in the field of signal processing, and now I have no time to study it. There is almost one week left for us to have this task done.
The main purpose of the work is to use different wavelet families and obtain the correct frequency spectrum **(amp-freq curve)**.

We are working with power quality and electromagnetic compatibility. This task is an engeneering task.

So here is the diference between datas. Original data is on the top and the interpolated is below.
[image: data]

Comment: Are you sure this is an amp-freq curve /the last one/ ? I can clearly see the Волт reading on the y-axis /U/, but am not sure that n is an indication of frequency...

Comment: It's my mistake, I'm sorry. I'll correct it.

Comment: Check now, please.

Comment: I have an idea and am trying to work on it right now. I will probably post an update tomorrow, but I have work + finals.

Comment: @Ivan, there are good answers already; just let me add that from an engineering perspective you have to consider other aspects of your problem: the limitations of your device (inside the "real industrial object"?); is this an ongoing issue or a single instance...? And the socio-engineering aspects: who is going to maintain that code, what sort of environment? Do you need to implement it in hardware or software? You certainly can run _Mathematica_ in a RaspberryPi, which is good news; but it all depends on the context of this problem.

Comment: Иван, а теперь ?

Comment: Ivan, any progress ?

Comment: Nothing :( Help me, please. I still need an appropriate amp-freq curve for my signal. And it is very important to get it with WaveletTransform. And we can't use FourierTransform, because of nonstationary interference. So we don't have a choice.

Comment: Well, you can use the STFT or FrFT. I think they suit you fine. There are questions about STFT here on Mathematica SE. Try searching them. And btw use @sektor so you can ping me otherwise I don't get notified when you comment.

Comment: @Sektor We were using STFT and now we need WaveletTransform.

Comment: @Sektor so should I be waiting for your help?

Comment: Yes, I will help you, but I have finals and am running out of time :D So, have patience

Comment: @Sektor OK, I'll be waiting. Thank you and good luck with your finals!

Comment: Is this satisfactory ?

Comment: @Sektor Sorry, but no. Please, could you relabel axes, adjust mags and convert scales/freqs in that exapmle? And WaveletScalogram with corverted scales/freqs is also desirable. 
I have less than a day for this task to be completed :(

Comment: @Sektor And also I think that your way to interpolate the data is inappropriate, because you changed the whole shape of the signal. Just try to make ListLinePlot for your "fdata" and my "data" and you'll see.
But my previous comment is more important at the moment.

Comment: And what is the difference between the two data sets ? You are telling me you can't scale the x-axis ? ...

Comment: I am sorry, but this is consuming too much of my time - I showed you the way you have to walk the rest of it. I showed you that my method works, why it works, but you still won't accept it...

Comment: @Sektor I'm very sorry and thank you a lot, but I think, that we just don't understand each other. I asked for something like http://i.stack.imgur.com/8KX7k.png but it was important to get it with WaveletTransform. You've done a lot of work, but it's not exactly what I need. 
Can I update my question to show what's wrtong with interpolation?

Comment: Well, I clearly reproduced this plot, but with less noise and I obviously used WaveletTransform - you can see the answer at the bottom of this page. There is no interpolation in my answers, so you are probably mistaken. Of course, you can always update your question.

Comment: @Sektor I meant that something's wrong your data interpolation. You'll see my question updated in a moment.

Comment: @Ivan Care to share what happened with this project ?

Comment: @Sektor it failed. Despite that it is very important to find out exact magnitude values which are represented by WaveletScalogram's color density even now. It would be great if you could and will help me with this task. And I think that Plot3D you proposed isn't such a good idea. Maybe it is possible to get an array or smth?

Comment: @Ivan I can't really do anything at this moment, because I don't have access to the data you used. If it is possible for you to share it again I can take a look at it this sat/sunday

Comment: @Sektor Link to the data is updated now.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks, I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: @Sektor thank you. I'll be waiting for your reply.

Comment: @Ivan Hi ! I am still waiting for your reply :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once again I repeat that trying to reproduce something like the curve you are trying to get is going to be inaccurate - There are more suitable representations you can use to get the desired frequency spectrum, but you are the one asking the questions :)

First, we fetch your data

```
data = Import[
       "http://www.fileconvoy.com/gf.php?id=geed872d9b8a38dc6999443310.
         4661369818fbd5fa1bf3bc&sts=138977900593152145247060b494909aee48bb2a26b595048647"];
```

Additional function we will use:

```
f[list_, pos_] := Module[{x = list}, x[[All, pos]] = Sequence[]; x]

fdata = Flatten@f[data, 1];

cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[fdata, MorletWavelet[], {6, 20}, SampleRate -> 500000]

WaveletScalogram[cwd, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", ImageSize -> 700]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[Total[Abs[#]^2] & /@ Reverse@cwd[All, "Values"], PlotRange -> All,
            ImageSize -> 700, BaseStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> ColorData[19, "ColorList"]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`WaveletScalogram` with the scale axis re-adjusted.

```
freq = (1000/(# MorletWavelet[]["FourierFactor"])) & /@
                (Thread[{Range[6], 1}] /. cwd["Scales"]);

ticks = Transpose[{Range[Length[freq]], freq}];

WaveletScalogram[cwd, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{ticks, Automatic}, Automatic}, 
             FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Frequency(Hz)"},
             ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ImageSize -> 700]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that you have to change `500 000` to the value of your `SampleRate`

NB: Bear in mind that the axes are not scaled ! First observe that the number of octaves multiplied by the voices is equal to the max number on the x-axis and then you can use the relationship to scale the y-axis: $$scaledMagnitude = \frac{2 \times Magnitude}{N}$$
where $N$ is the sample size.

To illustrate the method just described, consider the signal

$$Sin[16 π x] + Sin[4 π x]$$

```
ListLinePlot[Abs@Fourier@Table[N@Sin[16 π x] + N@Sin[4 π x], {x, 0, 32 π, .001}], 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 900}, {0, 170}}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The frequencies are clearly distinguishable.

Now do the following:

```
cwt = ContinuousWaveletTransform[Table[N@Sin[16 π x] + N@Sin[4 π x], {x, 0, 32 π, .001}], 
          MorletWavelet[]]

WaveletScalogram[cwt, ImageSize -> 700, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And again

```
ListLinePlot[Total[(Abs[#]^2)] & /@ Reverse@cwt[All, "Values"], ImageSize -> 700,  
    PlotRange -> All, BaseStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> ColorData[19, "ColorList"]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

There it is ... Do not forget to scale the axes accordingly !

Comment: As I understand, the y-axis is magnitude, but could you explain do we have on the result's x-axis, please? Also on the last picture you have two peaks with too different magnitude, but on the http://i.stack.imgur.com/bQarM.png those peaks' magnitudes are almost the same. So what's wrong? I just don't get it. And could you give me a bit more explanations about scaling the axes?

Comment: In addition I want to admit, that my signal is 50 Hz sine + some high-frequency iterference. And the magnitude of the biggest high-frequency impulse can be even compared with the original signal amplitude. But I don't see any magnitude peaks on high frequencies.

Comment: X axis - scales. What's wrong is that as I said trying to approximate the magnitude and frequencies this way is actually not the proper way to do so :D Yes, there's an equation in my answer. According to that equation you have to re-label the y axis, because as you can see the axes are data dependent. That's okay, but the true relationship is that described in my answer. You don't see peaks, because first: few samples; second: you are working with scales on the x axis. Transform the scales to pseudo-frequencies and there you have it.

Comment: I know it is a sine wave. I interpolated the data, re-sampled it, computed the wavelet transform and plotted its scalogram.

Comment: So are those magnitude-scale curves for my signal appropriate? And forgive my stupidity, but I don't understand your equation. We have 3999 samples (for 4000 points), that's right? Peak amplitudes of my sine and of the interference is near 150V both. So for the first curve (DiscreteWaveletTransform) we have 150 = Magnitude * (2/3999). Hence magnitude = near 3*10^5. But we don't have such numbers on the y-axis.

Comment: Nope, that's wrong, obviously the adjustedMagnitude is the quantity you will be calculating right now. And the sample size is 4000, not 3999. As I said that's the wavelet coefficients' magnitude beside the fact that it is not so accurate you see the drawbacks - you have to recalculate the axes ticks.

Comment: I don't understand. Don't know how to recalculate the axes ticks, don't know if your answer is right. Because there is something wrong with those curves. We should have one 50 Hz peak and some few hig-frequency peaks, but I don't see anything. Think we just might misunderstand each other.

Comment: Oh.. $adjMagnitude = \frac {2 * 10^{11}} {4000}$ Once again you should convert the scales to pseudo-frequencies. If you use more scales you will be able to see the corresponding bands descending or ascending accordingly.

Comment: (2/4000)*10^11 = 5*10^7, but we don't even have such numbers! Maybe I just didn't get the point of your answer. Could you show me an example with convertion scales to frequencies and relabeling axes? I'm a bit annoing, I know. Sorry for that.

Comment: There it is: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34333/extracting-information-from-the-result-of-continuouswavelettransform?rq=1)

Comment: It fails when I try to relabel x-axis for those cuves' plots. And for y-axis I want to "replace" for example 5*10^8 with recalculated 25*10^4, but don't know how to. Please, cuold you give me new example with relabeled axes, adjusted mags and converted scales/freqs? I'm experimenting with options, etc, but it's a complete disaster. I'm not strong in Mathematica syntax :( I'm not rushing you, but I still need help.

Comment: I again repeat that abusing the wavelet analysis in such a way is not the right method. If you still don't believe me read the first two paragraphs [here](http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/faq.html)

Comment: However if you still want to do this I will do it.

Comment: @Sektor I think you are right as explained in the link. It may also depend on the basis function. The main problem is Mathematica does not have a function such as scale2frequency as in matlab. It may be interesting to see the complete code for future use of the forum when you have time. see the link in dsp I think OP needs similar approach in Mathematica http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-can-i-plot-frequency-vs-magnitude-of-wavelet-transform

Comment: @s.s.o Thank you for the reference, I have come across it, but unfortunately was unable to download the OP's data (from DSP) and reproduce it. Yes, there is functionality that is currently missing and we will only gain from its implementation. And I can't help, but agree with you - it depends on the basis function :)

Comment: @Sektor to re-adjust WveletScalogram axes you used: freq = (1000/(# MorletWavelet[]["FourierFactor"])) & /@
                (Thread[{Range[6], 1}] /. cwd["Scales"]);
What does "1000" mean?

Comment: That's your `SampleRate`

Comment: @Sektor So is my SampleRate 1000 or 500000? I'm confused.

Comment: Well, you tell me :D :D You are the one with the task

Comment: @Sektor Oscilloscope data's SampleRate is 500000 for 20ms (50 Hz sine-wave full period). But the captured data only for 8ms, so we had 4000 points, therefore 4000 – is my original data's sample rate. But you said, that you re-sampled it.

Comment: I re-sampled it in order to obtain more information - In my example I just removed the time part of the signal

Comment: @Sektor Have you seen the update of my question? I's at the very bottom.

Comment: Yes, but a problem lies in the fact that the 2D data set is too small to produce a meaningful wavelet transform, that's why I removed the time part - in order to compute the wavelet transform

Comment: @Sektor what do we have on this plot? What are those magnitudes on y-axis? http://i.stack.imgur.com/xc04C.png
It is grom your post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34333/extracting-information-from-the-result-of-continuouswavelettransform?rq=1

Comment: @Ivan The plot is actually "magnitude in each scale vs octaves/band in the scale"

Comment: @Ivan Another way to plot only the scales you are interested in instead of all of them :)

Comment: @Sektor OK. But it is strange that we can see some magnitudes with numbers like 8-9 on the y-axis. http://i.stack.imgur.com/xc04C.png Why don't we see some values like 1? Because 1 is the amplitude of http://i.stack.imgur.com/pRGUJ.png. Or maybe I don't understand it correctly. Could you explain, please?

Comment: @Sektor so would you explain? Please, I need your help

Comment: @Ivan Excuse me for the big delays as I am currently preparing articles for publishing. You see such magnitudes, because they are the magnitudes of the wavelet coefficients, not the original signal.

Comment: The reason for this is the fact that the wavelet transform is ... hold your breath .. transform :) You have to convert scales to freqs and scale the magnitudes if you want to use different functionality than the built-in to interpret your data.

Comment: @Sektor oh, thanks. So what is the way to scale the magnitudes? And can we re-sign y-axis with these scaled mags? If it is possible, could you just show me an example, please? It would be great.

Comment: @Sektor hey, have you seen my last comment?

Comment: @Ivan I am sorry I was abroad for a really long time. I am seeking a solution, but can't offer you anything at the moment besides notes.

Comment: @Sektor, I understand. If you'll have any news about this task, let me know, please. 
I sipmly don't understand the meaning of those magnitudes and want to bring them to their real values.

Comment: @Sektor, I've solved this task, thank you for your help a lot.

Comment: @Ivan How did you do it ? Can you send me the notes/code ?

Comment: @Sektor I've got several solutions of thist task. I can get  instantaneous amplitude of every frequency component. I can build frequency spectrum for every time point (moment). And finally I can get 3D plot representing all this information - amplitudes, scales and time. All this I got used Morlet wavelet. One amplitude are 2*Abs(wavelet coefficient)/sqrt(scale).

Comment: @Ivan Can you send me the code ? Or give me a link to the files ?

Comment: @Sektor I have no access to my computer now. Maybe in a few days I'll be able to sent you smth, but not now. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Ivan It is ok :) I will be waiting for you :)

Answer (score 11):

Since you haven't provided any data I define something like:

```
data = 
  Table[ Sin[2 Pi t] 
        + 0.86 Sin[97 Pi t] Cos[46 Pi t] Sin[39 Pi t] Cos[19 Pi t] Exp[-102 (1/3 - t)^2],
        {t, 0.091, 0.519, 1/4095}];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Now let's demonstrate how `WaveletScalogram` depends on the choice of `ContinuousWaveletTransform` with various wavelets, we choose a few examples with different `ColorFunction`, appropriate choice strongly depends on a specific purpose of signal processing and the real data one deals with.

```
GraphicsGrid[
  Table[{ Plot[{Re @ #, Im @ #}& @ WaveletPsi[k[[1]], x], {x, -4, 4}, 
                PlotRange -> All, Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
          WaveletScalogram[ ContinuousWaveletTransform[ data, k[[1]], {7, 12}, 
                                                        SampleRate -> 4095], 
                            ColorFunction -> k[[2]]]},
        {k, {{ MorletWavelet[],      "BlueGreenYellow"}, 
             { GaborWavelet[3],      "AvocadoColors"}, 
             { MexicanHatWavelet[2], "DeepSeaColors"}, 
             { PaulWavelet[2],       "SolarColors"}}}], 
  ImageSize -> 930]
```

[image]

These scalograms should be sufficient to start experimenting with your own data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a Microsoft Excel file recieved from digital oscilloscope in field conditions. This file contains 4000 points (voltage-time curve) and I don’t even know should I approximate this data, and if I should, how can I done this task. The signal is nonstationary, so I can’t use Fourier Transform to get the correct frequency spectrum. Thus I should use Wavelet Transform to get amplitudes of every frequency component from my voltage-time curve. But I don’t know how.

Comment: I know exactly that my curve contains kHz-range components. Does this information influence on choosing an appropriate wavelet family (Morlet, Gabor, Mexican Hat, etc.)?

Comment: Can you post a link to the data ?

Comment: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g7e08c5d38c786f8a9994433105bb48028e26105cb

Comment: @Ivan You should try to update your question explaining all you know about your data, all you have tried to do in _Mathematica_ to process it, what you expect to get, etc. Perhaps I'll be able  to update my answer in 2 or 3 days since I'm in a business trip. When you give a clear exposition of the issue we'll take a closer look at your question and expectedly be able to provide a more detailed answer. You should know that signal processing capabilities of _Mathematica_ are relatively new so there are rather few experts in this field. Nonetheless we'll try to help.

Comment: @Artes My question is updated now.

Comment: @Ivan I can't work on it until this friday but then I will try to update it.

Comment: @Artes Thanks in advance. I'm looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative; we will discard the time values.

```
f[list_, pos_] := Module[{x = list}, x[[All, pos]] = Sequence[]; x]

data = Import[
"http://www.fileconvoy.com/gf.php?id=geed872d9b8a38dc6999443310.
     4661369818fbd5fa1bf3bc&sts=138977900593152145247060b494909aee48bb2a26b595048647"];

fdata = Flatten@f[data, 1];

cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[fdata, GaborWavelet[4], SampleRate -> 1000000]

freq = (1000000/(#*GaborWavelet[4]["FourierFactor"])) & /@ 
            (Thread[{Range[11], 1}] /. cwd["Scales"]);
ticks = Transpose[{Range[Length[freq]], freq}];

WaveletScalogram[cwd, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", ImageSize -> 500,
                 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{ticks, Automatic}, Automatic}, 
                 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Frequency(Hz)"}]
```

Now that's a clear [`WaveletScalogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WaveletScalogram.html)

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

```
data = Import[
"http://www.fileconvoy.com/gf.php?id=geed872d9b8a38dc6999443310.
     4661369818fbd5fa1bf3bc&sts=138977900593152145247060b494909aee48bb2a26b595048647"];

dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[data]

efrac = dwd["EnergyFraction"]

eth[x_, ind_] := If[(ind /. efrac) < 0.01, x*0., x] /; MemberQ[efrac[[All, 1]], ind]
eth[x_, ___] := x

fwd = WaveletMapIndexed[eth, dwd]

ListContourPlot[Abs@Reverse@Partition[Flatten[fwd[All, "Values"]], 4000], 
                   MaxPlotPoints -> 300, ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListContourPlot[Abs@Reverse@Partition[Flatten[dwd[{{_}}, "Values"]], 4000], 
                   MaxPlotPoints -> 300, ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see the difference.

---

Okay, let's have some fun.

First, the data

```
data = BinaryReadList["http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/ptbdb/patient056/
                        s0196lre.dat"];

pdat = Take[data, 2000];

cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[pdat, GaborWavelet[], SampleRate -> 1000]

WaveletScalogram[cwd, ColorFunction -> "FallColors", ImageSize -> 500]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Oh, that heart ... Does not look good ...

---

Expanding on Artes' work you can do the following:

```
data = Table[ Cos[4 Pi t] + 0.3 Sin[55 Pi t] Exp[- 86 (1/3 - t)^2], {t, 0, 1, 1/4095}];

cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, SampleRate -> 4096]

WaveletScalogram[cwd, ColorFunction -> "RoseColors"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Which gives us more information about the signal. And then

```
f = cwd["LinearScalogramFunction"]

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0., 0.999756}, {y, 0.299259, 515.371}, 
                ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", ImageSize -> 500]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 0.999755859375}, {y, 0.2992592856356853, 515.3711319499473},
      ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 200]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: I just don't understand.
I need to get frequency spectrum of nonstationary signal, which is performed as list of points using Wavelet Transform.

Comment: Look again at the scalogram.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But could you just explain, how can I get something like 
http://www.intechopen.com/source/html/6880/media/image15.jpeg
http://www.acoustics.org/press/155th/chapmanfig1.gif
using Wavelet Transform

Comment: Whoa, that's a whole different story. Notice how the the x-axis is Freq and the y - Amplitude. Well, the axes of the scalogram are time and scales... You can really easily plot the figure, but you have to construct a new data set consisting of values `{freq,amp}`

Comment: Yes, I thought that Wavelet Transform can be used, such as Fourier Transorm, but for nonstationary signal to get exactly what I need. So if I don't have anything except this Excel file, what should I do to see frequency spectrum at last? I'm sorry, if I couldn't explain correcty what I want.

Comment: It is better than the Fourier transform. Well, you see the spectrum. That's the relationship between scales and frequency: freq = 1 / scales. You are seeing the frequency spectrum; Look at the top of my answer - there's a plot showing a distinctive peak. And this actually answers your question. For more information look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34333/extracting-information-from-the-result-of-continuouswavelettransform/34353#34353).

Comment: But how can I find out amplitudes of every frequency components? It is very important thing for me to get a plot from {freq,amp} values. 
Before asking all the questions I read post that you linked and it was very helpful. But I still need freq-amp curve.

Comment: That's what the scalogram colour density represents - amplitude :) You should read about the time-frequency representation.

Comment: You are right, and I know that too. But I need numbers – exact amplitude values.

Comment: Then plot it in 3D using the method I showed you or use a contour plot, again, as I showed in the answer.

Comment: It is a good idea, but are you shure, that we can not discard time-axis, getting simply freq-amp curve?

Comment: You can do it, but again `WaveletScalogram` does not give you the frequency response - it gives you a good time and frequency localization along with the magnitude.

Comment: The frequency response is characterized by the magnitude of the system's response, typically measured in decibels (dB) or as a decimal, and the phase, measured in radians or degrees, versus frequency in radians/sec or Hertz (Hz).
These response measurements can be plotted in three ways: by plotting the magnitude and phase measurements on two rectangular plots as functions of frequency to obtain a Bode plot; by plotting the magnitude and phase angle on a single polar plot with frequency as a parameter to obtain a Nyquist plot;

Comment: or by plotting magnitude and phase on a single rectangular plot with frequency as a parameter to obtain a Nichols plot.

Comment: Thank you for all the work you've done. But it's not exactly what I need. I have the real engineering task to find out amplitude values from every frequency component. And this curve is from the real industial object. Thus, as an engineer, I care about numbers. I just should update my question, as Artes said, and add all the explanations I can.