# How to extract data from wavelet scalogram?

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

I've read several topics here concerning wavelets.
Especially [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34353/93115) is very useful where in the answer is explained how to convert default Mathematica scalogram into useful one (with frequency and time on the scale).
Moreover it was shown how to extract all the frequences via the code

```
freQ = (#1[[1]] -> sampleRate/#1[[2]] &) /@ cwt["Scales"]
```

But I still don't get how to exctract time-frequency information, i.e. what exact frequency exists in exact moment of time (or what band of frequency exists in exact moment of time, taking into account resolution issues aka uncertainty principle).
For my experimental data it's necessery for construction a plot of variation of the fundamental frequency (1st harmonic) in the wavepacket with time.
But for the sake of simplicity I offer to process 'classic' example data from the link above, e.g.

```
data = Table[Piecewise[{{Sin[2 π 10 t], 0 <= t < 1/4}, {Sin[2 π 25 t], 
  1/4 <= t < 1/2}, {Sin[2 π 50 t], 
  1/2 <= t < 3/4}, {Sin[2 π 100 t], 3/4 <= t <= 1}}], {t, 0, 
1, 1/1023}];
```

[image: classic example]

or a linear chirp waveform

```
data1 = Table[{x, Sin[2 Pi 1. x^2]}, {x, 0, 10, 1./1023}];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness@0.002}, AspectRatio -> 1/4]
```

[image: linear chirp waveform]

```
CWTtest1 = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data1[[All, 2]],  MorletWavelet[], {12, 16},(*WaveletScale\[Rule]1,*)  SampleRate -> 1023];

freq = (CWTtest1[
   "SampleRate"]/(#*
    CWTtest1["Wavelet"]["FourierFactor"])) & /@ (Thread[{Range[
    CWTtest1["Octaves"]], 1}] /. CWTtest1["Scales"]);

ticks = Transpose[{Range[Length[freq]], freq}];

WaveletScalogram[CWTtest1, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{ticks, Automatic}, Automatic},FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Frequency(Hz)"}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

where we have a growing 1 Hz frequency.
[image: chirp Scalogram]

Also I'd like to plot my 'own' scalogram via
ListContourPlot[{t1,w1,A1},{t2,w2,A2},...,{tn,wn,An}],
where t - time; w - frequency, A - amplitude.
Anyway, in order to do that we need {time,frequency} pairs of data..
Thanks in advance!
p.s. Apparently, I'm not the first one who is concerned with this problem here.
[At this topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162687/93115) guys were also questioned how to do that :-)