# Please explain this syntax: GaborWavelet[6]["FourierFactor"]

Tags: undocumented, wavelet-analysis

I've been using Mathematica for some years, yet I'm befuddled by this statement:

```
GaborWavelet[6]["FourierFactor"]
```

It appears to give the center frequency of the Fourier transform of the Gabor Wavelet, which I actually wanted.  But if I hadn't seen this command in a piece of [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34333/extracting-information-from-the-result-of-continuouswavelettransform), I never would have known the above command even existed in *Mathematica*.    I can't find `"FourierFactor"` anywhere in the *Mathematica* documentation.  Apparently, the `"FourierFactor"` is a property of the `GaborWavelet`.  But I didn't know a property like this could be accessed with a command.   I wonder what other properties the `GaborWavelet` might have? Can you explain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quite often, a Mathematica object can have properties, and typically you can find out what properties (or methods) are available by using "Properties" or "Methods". For example:

```
SparseArray[RandomReal[1, {3,3}]]["Methods"]
```

> {"AdjacencyLists", "Background", "ColumnIndices", "Density", "MatrixColumns", 
> "MethodInformation", "Methods", "NonzeroPositions", "NonzeroValues", 
> "PatternArray", "PatternValues", "Properties", "RowPointers"}

It seems to be an oversight that "Methods" is not supported for GaboWavelet. However, these properties are typically implemented using [`SubValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubValues), so you can do:

```
Select[StringQ] @ SubValues[GaborWavelet][[All, 1, 1, 1]]
```

> {"OrthogonalQ", "BiorthogonalQ", "WaveletFunction", "FourierTransform", 
> "CompiledFourierTransform", "FourierFactor", "ConeOfInfluence"}

to find out what other properties are available.

Comment: The documentation about these properties seems to be lacking.  Is a property like at Option?  Can I change the "AdjacencyLists" of SparseArray, for example?  When I go to the documentation for SparseArray, none of these properties are mentioned in the "properties & relations" section.

Comment: Seems that one needs to use `GaborWavelet` once before checking the subvalue e.g. `GaborWavelet[1]; SubValues[GaborWavelet]`, at least in _v12.1.1_.