# Is wavelet a Nonlinear transform, or Not?

Tags: wavelet-analysis

Is wavelet a Nonlinear transform, or Not?
 specifically, continuous wavelet transform with morlet function. I am studying behavior of a dynamic system, and it has nonlinear behaviour. can I employ wavelet transform?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33549/continuous-wavelet-transform-with-complex-morlet-function

Comment: it't not answering my question, actually the link you sent is my earlier question lol @WojciechSitkiewicz

Comment: Sorry, my bad :)

Comment: As much as I would like to answer your question - as it is asked right now - I does not belong to the MMA StakcExchange... Long story - short: It depends. Check out Wim Sweldens' articles on the subject.

Comment: where is the link of his article? @Sektor

Comment: Google ? A little bit of searching ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it may be a complicated question about whether the Continuous Wavelet Transform (CWT) in general is a linear operator, it is possible to answer the question "experimentally"  without undue hassle regarding *Mathematica*'s implementation of the CWT. Here are two sequences, `a` and `b` and their `ContinuousWaveletTransforms`:

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100];
cwta = ContinuousWaveletTransform[a];
cwtb = ContinuousWaveletTransform[b]; 
cwtab = ContinuousWaveletTransform[a + b];
```

To test for linearity

```
Max[Abs[cwta[All, "Values"] + cwtb[All, "Values"] - cwtab[All, "Values"]]]
1.11022*10^-15
```

which shows that the sum of the CWTs is the sum of the individual CWTs, except for numerical roundoff error. Similarly, you can verify that `ContinuousWaveletTransform[n*a + m*b]` is the same as `n*cwta+m*cwtb`. The same also holds when using the MorletWavelet[] option in the CWT.