# Fourier factor and Fourier transform for wavelet transform

Tags: wavelet-analysis

To define the continuous wavelet transform in Mathematica, you need Fourier factor and Fourier transform. I don't understand how to find these two, for example, how can define these two in the haar wavelet transform:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1}}]
g[x_] := f[2 x] - f[2 x - 1])
```

and these two are defined for `f[x_]` or `g[x_]`?

Comment: Is it not a duplication of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108963/how-to-define-a-new-wavelet-type ?

Comment: I saw the page you mentioned, but I don't understand how it defines Fourier transform and Fourier factor so that I can define these two for continuous wavelet transform, for example Morlet or shannon.